# Launching a InfluxDB container in docker with a default database name

Tags: docker, influxdb

I'm running the following command to launch a `InfluxDB` container. This should create a new databse with the name `defaultdb`.

```
docker run -p 8086:8086 \
      -e INFLUXDB_DB=defaultdb -e INFLUXDB_ADMIN_ENABLED=true \
      -e INFLUXDB_ADMIN_USER=admin -e INFLUXDB_ADMIN_PASSWORD=adminpass \
      -e INFLUXDB_USER=user -e INFLUXDB_USER_PASSWORD=userpass \
      -v influxdb:/var/lib/influxdb \
      influxdb:latest
```

But it doesnt create the default databse `defaultdb`. It creates the databse `db0` instead of `defaultdb`. What I'm doing wrong?

https://hub.docker.com/_/influxdb/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was due to the `INFLUXDB_ADMIN_ENABLED=true` line.

The documentation states:

> The administrator interface is deprecated as of 1.1.0 and will be
>   removed in 1.3.0.

I was using the `latest` version which is (currently) the `1.4` so it seems that there was a problem with that deprecated `INFLUXDB_ADMIN_ENABLED` variable.

Removing that line, everything worked perfectly.

```
docker run -p 8086:8086 \
      -e INFLUXDB_DB=defaultdb \
      -e INFLUXDB_ADMIN_USER=admin \
      -e INFLUXDB_ADMIN_PASSWORD=adminpass \
      -e INFLUXDB_USER=user \
      -e INFLUXDB_USER_PASSWORD=userpass \
      -v influxdb:/var/lib/influxdb \
      influxdb:latest
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is probably comming from the volume.

```
-v influxdb:/var/lib/influxdb
```

In particular, if you have previously created a database using the same command but without specifying the `INFLUXDB_DB=defaultdb`, this old database is overriding the container data via the old volume.
To solve the issue, remove the old volume and rerun the command:

```
docker volume rm influxdb
```

Comment: That command is taken directly from the docs. Thanks for the help anways, yamenk. The solution is explained in my answer.

Comment: this is exactly what happened to me. tnx