# How to create a database when launching the InfluxDB container in docker

Tags: docker, influxdb

I want to create a database at the launch of the InfluxDB container in docker. I went through this previously asked question [Launching a InfluxDB container in docker with a default database name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49066607/launching-a-influxdb-container-in-docker-with-a-default-database-name) which is about 3 years old.

By referring the solution of that question, I used the following command to run the image.

```
docker run -d --name influxdb -p 8086:8086 \
-e INFLUXDB_DB=databasenew \
-e INFLUXDB_ADMIN_USER=admin \
-e INFLUXDB_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin \
-v /var/lib/influxdb:/var/lib/influxdb \
influxdb:1.8
```

But, it doesn't create a new database named as "databasenew".

In the above docker command, I use `-v /var/lib/influxdb:/var/lib/influxdb` to mount my local influxdb data to the container.

When I use `-v influxdb:/var/lib/influxdb` in the docker command, it creates a database named as "databasenew". But the database location is not my local influxdb location.

So how to create the database when launching the influxdb container with host location (/var/lib/influxdb) mounted as the volume.

**Update**

After checking the logs, I realized that, if the mounted volume already has a database, docker avoid to create a new database even though the database names are different. If the volume is fresh and no databases exist, then docker engine creates the new database mentioned in `INFLUXDB_DB`

There can be situations which I want to create a new database in the existing volume. How can I achieve that ?

Comment: Do you see any warning logs?

Comment: @null No. There are no warnings or errors when I run that docker command.

Comment: Does `influxdb` container running properly? or in error or restarting stage?

Comment: @SachithMuhandiram `influxdb` container is running without any issue.

Comment: @MalithPrasannaRathnasena What about `influxdb` logs? does it have an error or warning?

Comment: @SachithMuhandiram /var/log/influxdb folder is empty. Am I looking at the wrong place for the log ? I'm using a raspberry-pi4 with Ubuntu OS

Comment: @MalithPrasannaRathnasena `docker ps` get your `influxdb` running ID, `docker logs <running-id>`

Comment: After checking the logs, I realized that,  if the mounted volume already has a database, docker avoid to create a new database even though the database names are different. If the volume is fresh and no databases exist, then docker engine creates the new database mentioned in `INFLUXDB_DB`

Comment: Can wrote that as an answer? So the question can be marked as solved.

Comment: @akop I can't consider it as a solution. Because there can be situations which I want to create a new database in the existing volume. I want to achieve that.

Comment: Sorry, I thought your question was solved. Is the volume empty? Other databases (like postgres) will only make the initialization, when there are no files inside the data-dir.

Comment: @akop Volume is not empty. It has previously created databases.

Comment: The docs aren't helpful? Have a loot at https://hub.docker.com/_/influxdb under "Custom Initialization Scripts"

Answer (score 0):

The commands you are using above are only valid to generate a new database. As you already discovered in the meantime. However, there is a chance to get rid of this old database.

Assuming your container hosts only one database at all, you could delete the content of your local directory, which is mounted into the container. The directory contains the information, which isn't there anymore and the container will initialize the database once more.

If you do have a more complex landscape, you can go with configuration scripts. Here I refer to the documentation of [influxdb docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/influxdb) inside the section of "Custom Initialization Scripts". Summarizing, there is a folder inside the influxdb docker container, where each script is executed, when the container starts. Here you could check for existence.

Answer (score 0):

When your container has been already initialized and you want to add additional Databases you can execute command inside container to create new one(for example `some_database`, so we need to execute `create database some_database;`

**Note:** I assume your container name is `influxdb`
We can make it in 2 ways:

### 1. Login into container then execute command

To login just execute:

```bash
docker exec -it influxdb bash
```

And then inside create database using:

```bash
influx -execute 'create database some_database;'
```

and just `exit` to leave container

### 2. One liner to do it at once

Execute command in container and exit at one

```bash
docker exec influxdb influx -execute 'create database some_database;'
```

### More help full command

To list all databases we can execute:

```bash
docker exec influxdb influx -execute 'show databases;'
```

If you want to remove some database that is no longer needed you do it by using

```bash
docker exec influxdb influx -execute 'drop database some_database;'
```